# Adjust max on all jQuery UI spinners after one changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the beta version of the jQuery UI spinner, as of jQuery UI 1.9 milestone 7.  What I'm trying to do is the following: I have a series of spinner inputs, all with the same class that I can use as a jQuery selector (.spinner).  These spinners are setting values for a set of objects, which all draw from the same "pool" of resources.  Each time a spinner's value is updated, I want to go through and update *all* spinners' max value based on how much of that resource pool remains.  Here is the basic code so far:

```
var unusedPool = 500;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.spinner').spinner({
        min: 0,
        max: (unusedPool + this.value),
        change: function(event, ui) {
            // An AJAX call which pushes the change to the DB,
            // and returns a JSON object containing the change in what remains
            // in the resource pool.
            jQuery.ajax({
               // URL, type, etc. etc.
               data: { newValue: this.value },
               success: function (data) {
                   unusedPool -= data.change;
                   // Here is where I need to go through and update *all* spinners,
                   // so their new "max" is their current value plus the new 
                   // unusedPoolSize.
               }
            }   
        }
});
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?  Do I need to bind an event to all spinners and then trigger that event, or is there a more direct way (within the change callback) to access all of the spinners and alter the "max" value?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could add something like this in the success function:

```
$('.spinner').each(function() {
  $(this).spinner().change(function() {
    $(this).spinner('option', 'max', $(this).spinner('value') + unusedPool);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is similar to what I eventually discovered myself, although not quite the same.  This would just change the max of the one spinner that triggered the change event.  I ended up looping through them - I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kvam's answer turns out to be very close, but the update inside the success function does not go inside of the spinner.change callback (since the .ajax call itself is inside the .change callback).  I eventually discovered that this does the job:

```
var unusedPool = 500;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var spinners = $('.spinner').each(function() {
        $(this).spinner({
            min: 0,
            max: (parseInt(this.value) + unusedPool),
            change: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    data: { newValue = this.value },
                    success: function(data) {
                        unusedPool -= data.change;
                        spinners.each(function() {
                            var newMax = parseInt(this.value) + unusedPool;
                            $(this).spinner({ max: newMax });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```